# Firebase pushes not showing in iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification

I try to fire push notification on iOS app using firebase. However, their not coming. I tried to make curl request and get following response:

```
{"multicast_id":4712776757180847780,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}Apple-...
```

What is - error not register meaning? How to make pushes work?

Comment: You are probably missing the APNS Cert - have you worked through the quickstart and looked at the sample? https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging

Comment: @RyanHeitner how to i see apns certificate by looking at example app?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<my key here>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  " data ": {
    "title": "Notification title",
    " body ": {
"name": "Body text",
}
  },
  "to": "<my token here>"
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```